# How to remove a default service from the .net core IoC container?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, ioc-container

One of the beautiful things about .net core is that it is very modular and configurable.

A key aspect of that flexibility is that it leverages an IoC for registering services, often via interfaces. This in theory allows for replacing a default .net service with a custom implementation of that service with very little effort.

This all sounds awesome in theory.  But I have a real work case where I want to replace a default .net core service with my own and I can't figure out how to remove the default service.

More specifically, in the Startup.cs `ConfigureServices` method, when `services.AddSession()` is called it registers a `DistributedSessionStore` vai following code:

```
 services.AddTransient<ISessionStore, DistributedSessionStore>();
```

as can be seen in the source code: https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/SessionServiceCollectionExtensions.cs

I'd like replace that ISessionStore with one of my own creation.  So if I have a class `RonsSessionStore:ISessionStore` that I want to use to replace the currently registered ISessionStore, how can I do it?

I know I can register my ISessionStore in the Startup.cs `ConfigureServices` method via the following:

```
 services.AddTransient<ISessionStore, RonsSessionStore>();
```

But how can I remove the already registered `DistributedSessionStore`?

I tried to accomplish this in the startup.cs `ConfigureServices` method via

```
 services.Remove(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<ISessionStore, DistributedSessionStore>());
```

but it had no effect and the DistributedSessionStore was still in the IoC container.  Any ideas?

**How does one remove a service from the IoC in the `ConfigureServices` method of the startup.cs?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the `ServiceDescriptor` class doesn't override `Equals`, and `ServiceDescriptor.Transient()` returns a new instance, different than the one in the collection.

You would have to find the `ServiceDescriptor` in the collection and remove it:

```
var serviceDescriptor = services.First(s => s.ServiceType == typeof(ISessionStore));
services.Remove(serviceDescriptor);
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm wondering, why would you still call `AddSession()` if you do not want to use the default implementation?

Anyway, you can try and use the `Replace` method for this:

```
services.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient<ISessionStore, RonsSessionStore>());
```

Quoting the docs:

> Removes the first service in `IServiceCollection` with the same service type as `descriptor` and adds to the collection.

Comment: The reason I still call AddSession() is that I still like being able to configure the cookie name, idleTimout and such through this method call and the standard infrastructure but I want to handle session storage differently.

Comment: I see, that makes sense.